# how to download and import glassfish source code into netbeans for web application

Tags: java, servlets, jakarta-ee, netbeans, glassfish

I'm currently trying to debug my beginner's web application that uses glassfish server. I was just wondering if there is a way to download the source code for glassfish, e.g. the glassfish implementation code for java abstract classes such as HttpServlet. I ended up at https://java.net/projects/glassfish/sources/svn/show but not sure how I could download the source code and add it to NetBeans so that the implementation code will show up whenever I press control-click in NetBeans, like what normally happen to standard oracle java class. 
[image]

Comment: netbeans -> team -> subversion -> checkout -> url: https://svn.java.net/svn/glassfish~svn

Comment: @DavidPérezCabrera thank you so much for the tip!